# IE8 - Not writing certain cookies on my machine

Tags: cookies, internet-explorer-8

I have a problem where I am using ASP.Net to write a cookie.  The code is correct and works great in Firefox and also works in IE on other machines.  My machine, however, does not want to play ball.  I have reset the settings in IE to no avail.  The only thing that makes it work is when I uncheck the `Protected Mode` in the security settings, but then I get an annoying pop-up everytime I open a new browser.

The plot thickens...

On other machines, this `Protected Mode` is checked and the cookie is being written.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this affects the Cookie issue, but:

With the IE 7 Protected Mode Turned On, the browser essentially runs as a low privilege process; as a result of which it can store / read / write cookies in the LOW version of the Cookies folder:

C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies\Low

But if you have turn UAC off or Disabled the Protected Mode in IE 7, in Windows Vista, they (like cache, temp & history) will mostly be stored in:

C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies