# Shopping basket becomes empty when moving between http & https

Tags: cookies, asp-classic, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

We have an existing site, built in Classic ASP and have recently moved from a 2003 Server to a 2008 R2 server and have got some odd behaviour.

It's a basic ecommerce system that uses a cookie to store the basket/cart id - the actual basket contents are stored in the database.

So, a user (using IE8 - we have not been able to recreate this on any other browser) adds items to their basket and are taken to the view basket page. The next stage of the checkout process changes from http to https, and suddenly the basket is empty - on investigation, the cookie is NOT being picked up.

We can recreate this issue by simply viewing the basket over http (all ok) and then https (basket empty) - this uses the same URL and do not open a new tab.

I've done loads of searching and can confirm that:
the application pool in IIS7.5 only uses 1 worker process
New ID On Secure COnnection is set to False in IIS
the domain name does NOT contain a hyphen (although the cookie value does)

Any advice is gratefully received as we're stumped and the client isn't happy...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem now identified: it was IE8 and it's protected mode settings! See [IE8 - Not writing certain cookies on my machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105435/ie8-not-writing-certain-cookies-on-my-machine) for more information...